# Laravel Eloquent - where with and

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-clause

Pic for table in blade:

[image]

and

See this pic for table in database:

[image]

In my advanced search I have 2 input box which is round 1 and round 2.
If I search for 1 in round 1 and also 1 in round 2 it should display only the data of id 1.
It's like:

```
$query->where(['column.round' => 1, 'column.score' => $request->score1] and ['column.round' => 2, 'column.score' => $request->score2]);
```

My question is how to have and operator with this to show only the data of id 1.

This is like multiple rows with the same id in 1 column.

Comment: not clear with your question you want to search column.round = 1 and  column.round = 2 both values in the same column round with and condition?

Comment: @pari Yes. And please see the picture i just added for tables in database and in blade.
If i search for 1 in round 1 and also 1 in round 2 it should be the first line only in pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfCEV.jpg the session id 1 only.

Answer (score 0):

if i get you right u only want one RAW back instead of a collection

if that is the case then:

```
$query->where(['round1' => 1, 'round2' => 1])->first();
```

Comment: I just added pictures for my tables in database and in blade.
Kindly check it thanks.
So if i search for 1 in round 1 and 1 also 1 in round 2 it should display the line of sessionid 1 only. Thanks.

Comment: i edited the answer based on your image & description

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code. Refer [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#parameter-grouping)

```
$query->where(function ($roundQuery) {
            $roundQuery->where('round', '=', 1)
                  ->orWhere('round', '=', 2);
        })
        ->where(function ($scoreQuery) use($request) {
            $scoreQuery->where('score', '=', $request->score1)
                  ->orWhere('score', '=',$request->score2);
        })
        ->get();
```